# Symfony form , Loading after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

When i send my post data, Symfony spends two or tree minute before inserting data into the database.
I want to show a loading image or message to my client tell him to wait until data inserted to database.

I don't know if this is possible without using ajax.

Comment: What are you doing that it has to work up to three minutes? First, i'd track down the bottleneck and try to optimize it. If that isn't possible, I'd implement a system so that those heavy loading operations are done in the background without interrupting the user. Else your users most likely will have a really bad user experience.

Comment: You could add javascript to show a loading spinner when the submit button is clicked but that will only work as long as the browser remains on that page waiting for a server response. If you're seeing a blank page while it loads you will have to use ajax.

Comment: There's definitly something wrong if your form takes that long to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys , Its resolved i added a class loading with a spinner using jquery its work now , But one other things , When you submit and click by error too times or tree times on your form symfony insert duplicated rows and it a bad practice , I don't know how to tell symfony to insert just one row and reset data .